# Propel generation errors

Tags: propel

I have never liked SQL, and was glad to find Propel.

My "schema.xml" looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="lifeplan" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <table name="event" phpName="Event">
        <column name="event_id" type="integer" size="11" required="true"  primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
        <column name="event_title" type="varchar" size="80" default="null" />
        <column name="event_desc" type="text"/>
        <column name="event_start" type="timestamp" required="true" default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" />
        <column name="event_end" type="timestamp" required="true" default="0000-00-00 00:00:00" />
        <index name="event_start">
            <index-column name="event_start" />
        </index>
    </table>
</database>
```

I correctly organized index column?

build.properties:

```
propel.database = pgsql
propel.project = lifeplan
```

The first error after running `propel-gen`:

```
propel > sql:

     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] | Generating SQL for YOUR Propel project!  |
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
[phingcall] Calling Buildfile 'C:\php\propel\generator\build-propel.xml' with ta
rget 'sql-template'
 [property] Loading C:\php\propel\generator\.\default.properties

propel > sql-template:

[propel-sql] Loading XML schema files...
Execution of target "sql-template" failed for the following reason: Error settin
g up column 'event_desc': Cannot map unknown Propel type 'TEXT' to native databa
se type.
[phingcall] Error setting up column 'event_desc': Cannot map unknown Propel type
 'TEXT' to native database type.
Execution of target "sql" failed for the following reason: Execution of the targ
et buildfile failed. Aborting.
[phingcall] Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
Execution of target "main" failed for the following reason: Execution of the tar
get buildfile failed. Aborting.
    [phing] Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
```

I change the TEXT on BLOB and get:

```
propel > om:

     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] | Generating Peer-based Object Model for   |
     [echo] | YOUR Propel project!                     |
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
[phingcall] Calling Buildfile 'C:\php\propel\generator\build-propel.xml' with ta
rget 'om-template'
 [property] Loading C:\php\propel\generator\.\default.properties

propel > om-template:

[propel-om] Loading XML schema files...
[propel-om] 1 tables found in 1 schema files.
[propel-om] Generating PHP files...
Execution of target "om-template" failed for the following reason: Unable to par
se default temporal value "'0000-00-00 00:00:00'" for column "event.event_start"
 [wrapped: DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timez
one settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_de
fault_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are
 still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.
 We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select
your timezone.]
[phingcall] Unable to parse default temporal value "'0000-00-00 00:00:00'" for c
olumn "event.event_start" [wrapped: DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to r
ely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezo
ne setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled
 the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set
 date.timezone to select your timezone.]
Execution of target "om" failed for the following reason: Execution of the targe
t buildfile failed. Aborting.
[phingcall] Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
Execution of target "main" failed for the following reason: Execution of the tar
get buildfile failed. Aborting.
    [phing] Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
```

Removing the default values for the third time, I got something already unable to cope:

```
propel > convert-conf:

     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] | Converting runtime config file to an     |
     [echo] | array dump for improved performance.     |
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
Execution of target "convert-conf" failed for the following reason: C:\php\prope
l\generator\build-propel.xml:575:20: C:\php\propel\generator\build-propel.xml:57
5:20: No valid xmlConfFile specified.
[phingcall] C:\php\propel\generator\build-propel.xml:575:20: C:\php\propel\gener
ator\build-propel.xml:575:20: No valid xmlConfFile specified.
Execution of target "main" failed for the following reason: Execution of the tar
get buildfile failed. Aborting.
    [phing] Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
```

Is there a solution to my problems?

Answer (score 4):

There's two initial problems, both easily fixed:

- `default="0000-00-00 00:00:00"` is an invalid date, and is correctly disallowed. It would be much better to switch off `required` and use null instead.
- As the error message says, you need to set `date.timezone` in your php.ini.

As for your type error, try "longvarchar" instead of "text". See the [supported types here](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/schema.html#text-types).